# 206 partial Content and a bucket for error ids or json element with 404 and overall 200 OK

Tags: json, rest, api, http-status-code-404

We have a requirement where we want to hit the apis for a list of ids as async requests.

If the id is not found we receive a 404 for the specific request.

I want to know out of the two options which is a better way to handle with situation where partial content returns 200 and 404 for some of the ids.

I have evaluated two approaches.

a. 
HTML Response code: 200

```
{
    "12": {
        "Response": "Success",
        "StatusCode": 200,
        "content": {
            "title": "Shipping",
            "body": ""
        }
    },
    "13": {
        "Response": "Success",
        "StatusCode": 200,
        "content": {
            "title": "Shippin11",
            "body": " "
        }
    },
    "14": {
        "Response": "Error",
        "StatusCode": 404,
        "ErrorMessage": "Content Not Found"
    }
}
```

b.HTML Response code: 206

```
{
    "data": {
        "12": {
            "Response": "Success",
            "StatusCode": 200,
            "content": {
                "title": "Shipping",
                "body": ""
            }
        }
    },

    "error": {
        "Response": "Error",
        "StatusCode": 404,
        "ids": [12, 13]

    }

}
```

Please share your thoughts.

thanks, aakash

Answer (score 0):

I think it's better to use HTTP **207 Multi-Status** respoince (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes#2xx_Success). It's better sute for you task. More details in rfc: https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4918#page-78 (and chapter "13.  Multi-Status Response").

Main idea is wrapp all requests in single "main". Main responce return HTTP 200 Ok status. Response body contain list of request's responses and some meta information about whole request: count of successed/error requests. Every single response (inside main) contein their response HTTP code (200/204/404/...) and data.

For you case it may look like:

```
{
    "data": [
        {
            "content": {
                "id": 12,
                "title": "Shipping",
                "body": ""
            },
            "status": 200
        },
        {
            "resource": null,
            "status": 404
        },
        {
            "content": {
                "id": 13,
                "title": "Shippin11",
                "body": ""
            },
            "status": 200
        }
    ],
    "metadata": {
        "failure": 1,
        "success": 2,
        "total": 3
    }
}
```

You can watch to drupal developer's inplementation:
https://gist.github.com/e0ipso/732712c3e573a6af1d83b25b9f0269c8

Another example for json-api: https://developers.getbase.com/docs/rest/articles/search/samples/batch

There is no single common perfect format, but all implementations are similar in general, but differ in detail.